# Easy Ruby http/curl API to program with

Tags: ruby, http, curl

I've been using Ruby for quite some time now, however unlike PHP, as far as I know there is not a standard http/Curl (fetching, processing forms) like library that is easy and powerful like PHP's `libCuRL` binding.

While `Net::HTTP` is part of the Ruby standard library, I always find that API hard to remember and program with.

Can anyone give suggestions on which http/curl library I should use over `Net::HTTP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) gem. It's got a pretty clean API and allows you to make concurrent requests.

Comment: Paul Dix, the original author of Typhoeus, has a [blog article](http://www.pauldix.net/2009/01/ruby-http-client-library-performance.html) comparing several different clients.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or [REST Client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).

Answer (score 0):

I'll second Ryan's recommendation for Typhoeus, and recommend [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) also. Both are very full featured and handle parallel 
requests easily.

For simple requests it's hard to beat `Open-URI` for its simplicity:

```
require 'open-uri'
html = open('http://www.example.com').read
```

If you're parsing a page it works great with Nokogiri:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wrapper for the Net:HTTP lib recently, its very very simplistic. I wanted something with a simple API that was easy to use and remember, it's been working well for me:

https://github.com/ctcherry/plain_http

Comment: I might ended up using your module. Given how simple it is and the segment errors that I'm getting with Typhoeus on Ruby 1.9.2